# Responsive plot titles in shiny dashboard with ggplotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, ggplotly

I have a fluid dashboard with lots of graphs created in ggplot and then rendered as ggplotly objects. The problem is that on smaller screens or minimised windows, [sometimes the plot titles are cut off](https://gyazo.com/dd9cea91d5ef9563c2a9f67560889c59).

Is there a way to dynamically wrap plot titles based on screen width, potentially with str_wrap()?

I've included a reproducible example below:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 4,
      plotlyOutput("plot1")
    ),
    column(
      width = 4,
      plotlyOutput("plot2")
    ),
    column(
      width = 4,
      plotlyOutput("plot3")
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

  output$plot1 <- renderPlotly({
    x <- mtcars %>%
      ggplot(
        aes(
          x = cyl,
          y = hp,
          fill = wt
        )
      ) +
      geom_point() +
      labs(title = "My very, very, very long title number 1")
    
    
    ggplotly(x)
  })
  
  output$plot3 <- renderPlotly({
    x <- mtcars %>%
      ggplot(
        aes(
          x = cyl,
          y = hp,
          fill = wt
        )
      ) +
      geom_point() +
      labs(title = "My very, very, very long title number 2")
    
    
    ggplotly(x)
  })
  
  
  output$plot2 <- renderPlotly({
    x <- mtcars %>%
      ggplot(
        aes(
          x = cyl,
          y = hp,
          fill = wt
        )
      ) +
      geom_point() +
      labs(title = "My very, very, very long title number 3")
    
    
    ggplotly(x)
  })
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be using `h4` tag instead of plot title, wrapping both `h4` and `plotlyOutput` with `column(fluidRow(...)` to make a responsive plot title and align the plot and `h4` title nicely.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 4,
      column(
        width = 12,
        fluidRow(
          column(width = 1, HTML("&nbsp;")),
          column(
            width = 11,
            h4("My very, very, very long title number 1")
          )
        ),
        plotlyOutput("plot1")
      )
    ),
    column(
      width = 4,
      column(
        width = 12,
        fluidRow(
          column(width = 1, HTML("&nbsp;")),
          column(
            width = 11,
            h4("My very, very, very long title number 2")
          )
        ),
        plotlyOutput("plot2")
      )
    ),
    column(
      width = 4,
      column(
        width = 12,
        fluidRow(
          column(width = 1, HTML("&nbsp;")),
          column(
            width = 11,
            h4("My very, very, very long title number 3")
          )
        ),
        plotlyOutput("plot3")
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Then you will have a responsive title, no matter how narrow your screen is.

Server code remains the same.

Comment: Excellent idea, however the renderPlotly() calls in my dashboard render different plots based on the picker input indicator selected - something I did not add in my very simplified example code. Is it possible to render the h4s (or any other html-style tag) in renderPlotly(), without having to do a seperate renderUI?

Comment: So far, the idea of using `renderUI` seems a way to me, couldn't think of another approach right now! @anorlondo